# Remove space before and after text in html table

Tags: html, css

I need to remove space before and after text in html table but it seems not working with me (in two first rows on the right)! what can I do to resolve this issue. You can find below my code and I would like to have a table without huge spaces between rows.

***code***:

```
<table style=" width: 307.15pt; border-collapse: collapse;  table-layout: auto;

">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="5" style="width: 154.6pt;
             border-right: 2.25pt groove windowtext; padding:  5.4pt;
             vertical-align: middle; text-align:center;">
             <img height="100" src="/SigEditorHelper/GetEImage?ImgName=Webpnet-resizeimage1.jpg"
             width="180" /></td>
            <td style="width: 152.55pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt;
             vertical-align: top;">
            <p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: 0.0001pt
            ;text-align: center; line-height: 105%;"
            ><font face="Ford Antenna Regular, serif">
                <span style="font-size: 19px;">(!DisplayName!)</span></font></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom:6px; width: 152.55pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt;
             vertical-align: top;">
            <p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: .0001pt;
             text-align: center; line-height: 105%;">
             <font color="#a6a6a6" face="Ford Antenna Regular, serif">(!Position!)</font></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 152.55pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; ">
            <p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: .0001pt;  line-height: 105%;">
                <span style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 105%;
            font-family: 'Ford Antenna Regular',serif;">M&nbsp; (!Mobile!)</span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 152.55pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; ">
            <p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: .0001pt;  line-height: 105%;">
                <span style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 105%;
            font-family: 'Ford Antenna Regular',serif;">T &nbsp; (!Phone!)</span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 152.55pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;">
            <p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: .0001pt;  line-height: 105%;">
                <span style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 105%;
            font-family: 'Ford Antenna Regular',serif;">P.O. Box &nbsp;31279</span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 154.6pt;
            border-right: groove windowtext 2.25pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;
             ">
            <p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: .0001pt;  text-align: center;
             line-height: 105%;"><span style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 105%;
            font-family: 'Ford Antenna Regular',serif;">Naseejco.com</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 152.55pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; ">
            <p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: .0001pt;  line-height: 105%;">
                <span style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 105%;
            font-family: 'Ford Antenna Regular',serif;">Saudi Arabia, Jeddah, 21497</span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

***Result:***

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1WX0.png)

Comment: Do you have any additional CSS? If So please edit the question with it. Also, are you using any padding? That can also be why if so.

Comment: no all CSS are included here in html.

Comment: Try reducing the padding. That can help get rid of the space. You can also change the font sizes. Let me know if it works.

Comment: even after reducing the padding still there is space after the text. how can I control that?

Comment: Actually I think it might be the line height. I just changed that and I think I got it to shrink a little, but It could also just be my browser so give it a try changing ```line-height: 105%``` to something smaller.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```html
    <table style=" width: 307.15pt; border-collapse: collapse;  table-layout: auto;

">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="5" style="width: 154.6pt;
             border-right: 2.25pt groove windowtext; padding:  5.4pt;
             vertical-align: middle;">
             <img height="100" src="/SigEditorHelper/GetEImage?ImgName=Webpnet-resizeimage1.jpg"
             width="180" /></td>
            <td style="width: 152.55pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt;
             vertical-align: top;">
            <p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: 0.0001pt
            ; line-height: 105%;"
            ><font face="Ford Antenna Regular, serif">
                <span style="font-size: 19px;">(!DisplayName!)</span></font></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom:6px; width: 152.55pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt;
             vertical-align: top;">
            <p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: .0001pt;
             line-height: 105%;">
             <font color="#a6a6a6" face="Ford Antenna Regular, serif">(!Position!)</font></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 152.55pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; ">
            <p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: .0001pt;  line-height: 105%;">
                <span style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 105%;
            font-family: 'Ford Antenna Regular',serif;">M&nbsp; (!Mobile!)</span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 152.55pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; ">
            <p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: .0001pt;  line-height: 105%;">
                <span style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 105%;
            font-family: 'Ford Antenna Regular',serif;">T &nbsp; (!Phone!)</span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 152.55pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;">
            <p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: .0001pt;  line-height: 105%;">
                <span style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 105%;
            font-family: 'Ford Antenna Regular',serif;">P.O. Box &nbsp;31279</span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 154.6pt;
            border-right: groove windowtext 2.25pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;
             ">
            <p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: .0001pt;  text-align: center;
             line-height: 105%;"><span style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 105%;
            font-family: 'Ford Antenna Regular',serif;">Naseejco.com</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 152.55pt; padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; ">
            <p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: .0001pt;  line-height: 105%;">
                <span style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 105%;
            font-family: 'Ford Antenna Regular',serif;">Saudi Arabia, Jeddah, 21497</span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You wanted to do in here remove the text-align:center;